# Custom control of multiple seek bars

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have 5 seek bars in an Activity that are working perfectly. Their min/max are each set from 0 to 100. I need to make sure that at least one of the seek bars is always at its max level- 100. For example if sb1=sb2=sb3=sb4=50 and sb5=100 then sb5 is unable to move but sb1-4 remain moveable. If sb2 is moved to 100 then all sb's are enabled. How do I edit my CASE statements below or is there a better way to achieve this?

````
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) 
{

    switch (arg0.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.sb1:
        tv1.setText(arg1);
        break;
    case R.id.sb2:
        tv2.setText(arg1);
        break;
    case R.id.sb3:
        tv3.setText(arg1);
        break;
    case R.id.sb4:
        tv3.setText(arg1);
        break;
    case R.id.sb5:
        tv3.setText(arg1);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}```
````

Comment: This is a bit confusing. So one is at 100 and disabled but another gets to 100 too, then what happens? Can multiple items be at 100 or it's always 1?

Comment: Agreed, it is confusing! If one is the only one at 100 then it is unable to move. If more than one is at 100 then all can move. So multiple bars can be at 100 but when only one remains, it cannot move until another returns to 100.